# Operator value in where condition php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I do this?

```
SELECT sum(buy-sale) as istock form tbl_product
where istock > 0
```

I am not interested in the following method.

```
SELECT sum(buy-sale) as istock form tbl_product
where sum(buy-sale)> 0
```

Comment: Regarding your first query, are you sure that you didn't possibly omit a `GROUP BY` clause there?  If not, then just run the query and assert the sum from your PHP code...I don't see why there is any question here.

Comment: *I am not interested in the following method* - not sure what you mean and why you think it would work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace `WHERE` by `HAVING` ;-)

```sql
SELECT SUM(`buy-sale`) AS `istock` FROM tbl_product HAVING `istock` > 0
```

But this will return the sum of all your records. Normally you do that when you group by a criteria, such as a product id or whatever. For example:

```sql
-- Find big orders
SELECT 
    `order_number`,
    SUM(`quantity_ordered`) AS `quantity_sum`,
    SUM(`product_price` * `quantity_ordered`) AS `total`
FROM
    order_details
GROUP BY 
   `order_number`
HAVING 
   `total` > 1000;
```

This might help: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx